# can anyone give me a sql query for the following table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named eprism_reports and the table is as follows

[image]

In this table when I am using the query

```
SELECT  * 
FROM eprism_dashboard.eprism_reports 
where CARRIER_NAME='QA_T_MOB'
```

I am getting the following Resultset 
[image]

SO after getting the result set again I want to remove the duplicate TAG_NAME and in that duplicate TAG_NAME unique TAG_NAME should appear and RERUN should be max

Example: In the Resultset we are having Two tagnames duplicated name mytag I want a unique one with ReRUn should be MAX and Remaining ResultSet as usual.Please help me on this

The Expected Result Should be as follows:

```
id  CARRIER_NAME CLAIM_TYPE STATUS   DATE       TAG_NAME  RERUN
9   QA_T_MOB    Approved    Passed  2018-05-15  Theft       0
10  QA_T_MOB    Denied      Passed  2018-05-15  Denied      0
11  QA_T_MOB    In Review   Passed  2018-05-15  In Review   0
12  QA_T_MOB    Approved    Failed  2018-05-15  mytag       1
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (Formatted text...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `subquery` with *correlation* approach :

```
select e.* 
from eprism_reports e
where CARRIER_NAME='QA_T_MOB' and
      id = (select id 
            from eprism_reports
            where TAG_NAME = e.TAG_NAME
            order by rerun DESC
            LIMIT 1);
```

You can also express this as:

```
select e.* 
from eprism_reports e
where CARRIER_NAME='QA_T_MOB' and
      RERUN = (select max(RERUN) from eprism_reports where TAG_NAME = e.TAG_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TAG_NAME, MAX(RERUN) 
FROM eprism_dashboard.eprism_reports 
where CARRIER_NAME='QA_T_MOB'
GROUP BY TAG_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks your answer Helped to get my output

Answer (score 1):

You can try a query like this => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/057184/1

Select `Max(rerun)` value for each `tag group`, then query you table by `joining on rerun and tag column`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   eprism_reports t
JOIN   ( SELECT MAX(rerun) rerun
              , tag
         FROM   eprism_reports
         GROUP  BY tag ) t2
  ON( t.tag   = t2.tag
  AND t.rerun = t2.rerun )
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest rerun row per group you can do a self join

```
select a.* 
from eprism_reports a
left join eprism_reports b on a.CARRIER_NAME = b.CARRIER_NAME
                           and a.TAG_NAME = b.TAG_NAME 
                           and a.RERUN < b.RERUN
where a.CARRIER_NAME='QA_T_MOB' 
and b.CARRIER_NAME is null
```